# Setar data atual no Input type Date

Tags: html, input, data

Quero setar a data atual neste input type date; utilizando desta forma com php ele apenas da o valor da data atual, mas visualizando mostra apenas dd/mm/aaaa, mas inspecionando o código o valor da "value" esta com a data atual. Alguem pode me ajudar ?

```
 <input class='col-4' type='date' name='Dsaida' id='DSaida' value='<?php echo date("d/m/Y"); ?>'>
```

Answer (score 4):

Você deve passar a data nos padrões definidos no [RFC 3339](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html-markup-20110405/input.date.html), dessa forma:

```
 <input class='col-4' type='date' name='Dsaida' id='DSaida' value='<?php echo date("Y-m-d"); ?>'>
```

O [RFC 3339](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html-markup-20110405/input.date.html) é um perfil do [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), e ele define um formato para representação de datas e horas para a internet usando o calendário gregoriano.

Comment: Obrigado, deu certo

Comment: Só um detalhe: o formato `ano-mês-dia` é chamado [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) (o formato americano seria `mês/dia/ano`). E a [RFC 3339 é um *profile* da norma ISO 8601](https://stackoverflow.com/a/522281) (é como se a RFC fosse uma extensão/subconjunto da ISO, pois restringe alguns formatos enquanto permite outros, etc)

Comment: Obrigado @hkotsubo, modifiquei minha resposta.

Answer (score 0):

Se estiver usando JavaScript vc pode fazer essa gambiarra:

```
<script>    
//seta a data atual
     document.getElementById("campoData").value = value='<?php echo date("Y-m-d"); ?>';
</script>
```